# Результат GET'а не на новой странице

Tags: c#, json, asp.net

Есть контроллер с двумя методами

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
    public JsonResult JSResult()
{
    return Json(MakeAnswer.MakeString(Request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

В Index есть форма для отправки данных на сервер

```
<form method="get" action="JSResult">
```

Как сделать, чтоб результат после нажатия Submit отобразился на первой странице в другом div-блоке?

Comment: форма вручную написана в разметке?

Comment: сам писал, файл .cshtml

Comment: можно посмотреть в сторону [@Ajax.BeginForm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd460243(v=vs.118).aspx)